# jquery call other self-declared function in autocomplete select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Can I call a function in autocomplete select event?

I have a function call `getResult()` which will retrieve data from database, the function is working smooth, just I fail to call this function in autocomplete's select event. Below is my code:
**Auto-complete code:**

```
$(function()
{
    //auto complete for facultyID
    var availableTags = <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT FacultyID from tblfaculty";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $DBLink) or die("Error " . mysql_error($DBLink));

    $id_list = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id_list[] = $row['FacultyID'];
    }
    echo json_encode($id_list); ?>;

    $("#FacultyID").autocomplete(
    {
        source: availableTags,
        autoFocus:true,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
            getResult();
        }
    });
});
```

**getResult() function:**

```
function getResult()
{
    $(function()
    {
        var Semester = $('#Semester').val();
        var Year = $('#Year').val();
        var Course = $('#Course').find(":selected").val();
        var Subject = $('#Subject').find(":selected").val();
        var FacultyID = $('#FacultyID').val();
        var TimeSlot = $('#TimeSlot').val();
        var Location = $('#Location').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax_get_time_table.php', 
            data: {Semester:Semester+", "+Year, Course:Course, SubjectID:Subject, FacultyID:FacultyID, TimeSlot:TimeSlot, Location:Location},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data['error'] == null)
                {
                    if(data['no_result'] == null)
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error: " + data['error'])
                }
            },
            error: function(ts)
            {
                alert("AJAX Error: \n" + ts.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: What autocomplete library are you using? Any docs please?

Comment: you don't need ready function `$(function(){ .... }` inside a `getResult()`  function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put everything in a doc ready block in `getResult()` function:

```
$(function(){});
```

because the DOM is already loaded and you are able to call this function inside autocomplete's `select` event.